# Android material design list buttons, what are they called?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

If you take a look in the "Recents" tab in the newest Android Phone App you'll find that when you click on a contact, it expands and two buttons appear (Call back and details). Take a look in the picture below:
[image]

What are they called? I've browsed through the [Material Design element specification](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types), but I can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "flat" buttons. You can take a look at the documentation here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html

Comment: Is there a name for the expandable list item type?

Comment: @tsorn see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389052/how-can-i-implement-a-material-design-expand-collapse-list-on-android